# Looking to understand line artifacts in "overscanned" image

Tags: image-processing, camera

Essentially I'm looking for an explanation how the second image results from a capture of the original. Possibly you've seen something like this before and you can tell just from looking at the result what's going on.

- The original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBJ6P.jpg
- The output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh89O.jpg

Here's the capture process **using Android 4.0.4**:

1. Display original image on LCD monitor.
2. Set rear-facing camera on an LG VS840PP with parameter `picture-size=3072x1728`. Although this is listed as a setting in `picture-size-values`, it may not be completely valid. The other settings (e.g. 2560x1920) are 4:3 and produce typical images. `picture-format` remains set to `jpeg`.
3. Point camera at original image on monitor.
4. `takePicture()` via jpeg callback.
5. The resulting intermediate image, i.imgur.com/qw688u8.jpg (3072x1728), is resampled to produce the output image (2592x2048) using the Python Imaging Library code below.

   ```
   import Image
   inm = Image.open("pattern-in.jpg", "r")
   pixels = inm.getdata()

   width = 2592
   height = len(pixels) / width
   outm = Image.new( "RGB", (width, height), (128,128,128) )

   outm.putdata(pixels)
   outm.save("out.jpg")
   ```

I am not interested in getting the camera to work "properly". I'm more curious to understand just what's going on. I'm including another set of images taken of only black with the lens obscured.

- camera output: i.imgur.com/BygbqKF.jpg
- after resampling: i.imgur.com/uWjNXxZ.jpg

Also here is the EXIF data provided by the camera for the color bar photo:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.70
File Name                       : pattern-in.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 3.1 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2014:11:11 16:09:16-08:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2014:11:11 16:10:43-08:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2014:11:11 16:10:43-08:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : JPEG
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : LG Electronics
Camera Model Name               : VS840PP
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exposure Time                   : 1/30
F Number                        : 2.4
ISO                             : 654
Exif Version                    : 0220
Date/Time Original              : 2002:12:08 12:00:00
Create Date                     : 2002:12:08 12:00:00
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 4.3 mm
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 3072
Exif Image Height               : 1728
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version        : 0100
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 550
Thumbnail Length                : 35981
Image Width                     : 3072
Image Height                    : 1728
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 2.4
Image Size                      : 3072x1728
Shutter Speed                   : 1/30
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 35981 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Focal Length                    : 4.3 mm
Light Value                     : 4.7
```

Thanks very much!